# Installing python modules in order heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I'm trying to push my app that uses module: `fix-yahoo-finance`, however in order to install that module i need to install module called `yfinance` first.
So I placed `yfinance` module at top of requirements.txt list and the other one at the bottom. However when I push my app to heroku it still gives me an error:

```
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/f3/aba3b563452faaea71b4161754991e3143751ec9141d83c4bce05992332a/fix-yahoo-finance-0.1.37.tar.gz
remote:            Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
remote:            Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:              File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-k3a2lnr1/fix-yahoo-finance/setup.py", line 19, in <module>
remote:                from fix_yahoo_finance import __version__
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-k3a2lnr1/fix-yahoo-finance/fix_yahoo_finance/__init__.py",
line 22, in <module>
remote:                import yfinance
remote:            ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yfinance'
remote:
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-k3a2lnr1/fix-yahoo-finance/
```

So I wonder what Im doing wrong. And how to fix this issue?

Comment: Don't depend on ordering in your `requirements.txt`; let the dependency manager do its job. If `fix-yahoo-finance` depends on `yfinance` it should list it in its dependencies. Apparently [it doesn't](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/blob/56bc9ebdbc5490e8e555f9f7fc367487758da041/setup.py#L52). In my opinion this is a bug. I've [submitted an issue asking if there's a reason for this](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/79).

Comment: Thats seems to be the case, thanks.

Comment: Actually it seems that the second package is no longer in use and I should be able to use yfinance only.